# Javascript array.filter changing type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, types

[image: This is the original state inside react]
[image]

The below function is inside a React Class Component.
When the function is called this.state.data.Date `type` changes to `Date` when originally it was a  `string`. I need this to be a String and confused on how to prevent this from happening?

```
getYear = e => {
    let year = e.target.value;

    let start = new Date("01/01/" + year);
    let end = new Date("12/31/" + year);

    let filtered = this.state.data.filter(data => {
      let day = data.Date.slice(0, 2);
      let month = data.Date.slice(3, 5);
      let year = data.Date.slice(6, 10);

      return (
        new Date(year, month, day) >= start && new Date(year, month, day) <= end
      );
    });

    this.setState({ setData: filtered });
  };
```

Comment: If you console log `this.state.data` on the first line of the `getYear` function, are your dates still strings?

Comment: @EdLucas Yep, all formatted "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: You should provide a full executable code on a platform like jsfiddle.net

Comment: None of the code shown mutates your `data` array, eg `state.data[0] =...` or `setState({data:...})` nor the objects inside, eg `data.Date = ...`. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code

Comment: Also note since your array is made of objects and you are not cloning the data into `setData` if code manipulates any object it is going to be reflected in both `state.data` and `state.setData`